# Growh generating function for finite Heisenberg groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs, heisenberg-group

Take standard 2d-Heisenberg group over finite ring Z/p. Choose standard generators $x_i, y_i$.

Consider generating polynomial for growth: $ g(t) = \sum_i g_i t^i $ , where $g_i$ are the ball sizes.

What is the explicit expression for g(t) ?

It should be not so complicated and quite well-known. But I cannot Google it.

PS

Heisenberg is central extension of $(Z/p)^2d$ by $(Z/p)$.
The expression for g(t) for these groups are clearly quite simple- just take d-th power of the one for $Z/p$.
Thus for Heisenberg it should not be much more complicated.

Also we can expect that polynomial should close to d-th power of some smaller polynomial (but can be combination of several polynomials)  . To ensure approximate Gaussian distribution for ball sizes.

Comment: What do you mean by a "2d Heisenberg group?" The smallest algebraic Heisenberg group I know is 3-dimensional in any meaningful sense. To talk about group growth you have to choose a generating set. Integer 3d Heisenberg groups have growth function $n^4$ by the Bass–Guivarc'h formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth)).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/466094/10446 some simulations